# Можно ли в C# создать функции с одинаковым названием, но с разными аргументами?

Tags: c#, ооп

Можно ли в языке c# создать функцию с одинаковым названием, например `public static void Test()`, но в скобках указать разные переменные, например

```
public static void Test(int num);
public static void Test(string teststring)
```

Comment: Так попробуйте, какие проблемы?

Comment: А что мешает для разных переменных?

Comment: Можно! Это называется перегрузкой методов.

Comment: @monomax, спасибо. Я думаю вы можете оформить это как ответ.